# change output depending on the component

Tags: reactjs

> I have function, that shows the error, when user's trying to add skill or category on website. The error is unique, and I want to change the error text, depending on the skill or category.

```
export const UniqueNameError = (error: any) => {
    const { selectedNodeId, showActionDialog: handleNodeAction } = useTaxonomyContext()
    if (!error) return null
    return (
        <NameErrorContainer>
            <ErrorLabel>Skill name should be unique,</ErrorLabel>
            <ErrorButton onClick={() => handleNodeAction(selectedNodeId!, ActionType.CREATE_SHORTCUT)}>
                <u>add a shortcut instead?</u>
            </ErrorButton>
        </NameErrorContainer>
    )
}
```

and the return for the skill ( there is structurally the same for the category )

```
return (
        <ActionDialogWrapper
            title={'Add new skill'}
            buttonText="Add"
            disabled={!nodeTitle || error}
            submitAction={() => createNode(nodeTitle, ActionType.CREATE_SKILL, selectedNodeId)}
        >
            <SDialogLabel>to {reactFlowNodesMap[selectedNodeId!]?.data.label}</SDialogLabel>
            <TextField
                id="new-skill-input"
                value={nodeTitle}
                placeholder={'Type Skill Name'}
                label={'New Skill Name'}
                onChange={(e) => setNodeTitle(e.target.value)}
                autoFocus={true}
            />
            {UniqueNameError(error)}
        </ActionDialogWrapper>
    )
```

How can I change the string 'category name should be unique', so that can change for skill and category?

Answer (score 0):

I cant see in the code what error suppose to be, however you function does not take an error as an argument anyways. I would just use `UniqueNameError` as a component and pass the error label as a property

```js
export const UniqueNameError = ({error, errorLabel}) => {
    const { selectedNodeId, showActionDialog: handleNodeAction } = useTaxonomyContext()
    if (!error) return null
    return (
        <NameErrorContainer>
            <ErrorLabel>{errorLabel}</ErrorLabel>
            <ErrorButton onClick={() => handleNodeAction(selectedNodeId!, ActionType.CREATE_SHORTCUT)}>
                <u>add a shortcut instead?</u>
            </ErrorButton>
        </NameErrorContainer>
    )
}

return (
    <ActionDialogWrapper
        title={'Add new skill'}
        buttonText="Add"
        disabled={!nodeTitle || error}
        submitAction={() => createNode(nodeTitle, ActionType.CREATE_SKILL, selectedNodeId)}
    >
        <SDialogLabel>to {reactFlowNodesMap[selectedNodeId!]?.data.label}</SDialogLabel>
        <TextField
            id="new-skill-input"
            value={nodeTitle}
            placeholder={'Type Skill Name'}
            label={'New Skill Name'}
            onChange={(e) => setNodeTitle(e.target.value)}
            autoFocus={true}
        />
        <UniqueNameError error={error} errorLabel={"Skill name should be unique,"}/>
    </ActionDialogWrapper>
)
```

Comment: question edited. didin't check updates. Want to do this with props @Disco

Comment: Just pass error as a prop as well, se updated answer.